# CSS file is not being loaded dynamically via ng-href

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to dynamically load different css styles into my page using `ng-href`, but the page is not being updated with the activated style. Code is as follows:

```
<html ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myController as myctrl">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="../assets/css/{{ myctrl.style }}.css">
    </head>
</html>
```

In my controller, I do the following:

```
vm.style = "redStyle";
pub.subscribe('style', function(theStyle) {
    vm.style = theStyle;
});
```

The variable in the `subscribe` is updated with the new style once a publish has taken place. But the respective css file is not being loaded such that the style is updated on the page. Any ideas what I am missing out on?

Comment: You have two //

Comment: can you check in the dev. console if it returns a "404 - file not found"?

Comment: Sorry, the additional "/" was a typo.

Comment: Can you upload a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/)

Comment: Without being able to try out your code (see above), I posted a possible solution. Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/lmTlcFdBpumjMzZo33we?p=preview)

It's very much the same as what you have so it's something else in your code. Hard to tell unless you put up all your code.

Assuming the stylesheet actually does exist, and the style variable is getting updated then my guess is that the culprit is

```
pub.subscribe()
```

If this callback is being triggered by something outside of angular then angular wont see the updated variable. You can bring it back into angular space like so:

```
pub.subscribe('style', function (theStyle) {
  $scope.$apply(function(){
      vm.style= theStyle; 
  });               
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" data-ng-if="myctrl.style" data-ng-href="../assets/css/{{ myctrl.style }}.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it differently.
In my html, I gave the link element an id:

```
<link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" ng-href="../assets/css/{{theme}}.css">
```

And in the controller I say:

```
var myTheme = document.getElementById("theme");
var path = "../assets/css/{{theme}}.css";
myTheme.href = path.replace("{theme}", theme.class);
```